# In a custom ESLint rule's fixer, is there a simple way to remove node together with a following newline?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

In a custom rule (strictly speaking, one for [typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io/developers/custom-rules/), but I don't expect it to matter for the answer), I want to remove an `ImportDeclaration` node in some cases. The issue is that when I simply include

```
fixer.remove(node)
```

in the array of fixes I end up with an empty line; the line break after the node doesn't get removed. Is there a convenient way to remove that line? I use

```
const [start, end] = node.range;
fixer.removeRange([start, end + 1])
```

but that assumes the newline is always there. Which is a reasonable assumption for an import declaration, and trying to check it complicates the code for other reasons (`fixer.removeRange` is actually in a branch of a ternary operator).

But maybe there is a nicer way to avoid the empty line which I failed to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually check the node's source file text using `context.sourceCode.text`. See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/custom-rules#accessing-the-source-code.

For example, this will increment the end range of a removal while it's a `\n`:

```js
let end = node.range[1] + 1;

while (context.sourceCode.text[end] === "\n") {
  end += 1;
}

fixer.removeRange([node.start, end + 1])
```

Though - you're right to question whether this logic is important. Most custom ESLint rules these days assume a separate formatter will be used after the fact to clean up whitespace such as newlines. typescript-eslint in particular pretty strongly recommends against caring about formatting concerns in lint rules: https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting/formatting. So, you're fine to stick with the  `+1` technique as described.